# basis for finite fields as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

If we consider GF(4) as a vector space over GF(2), the basis of GF(4) includes two elements 1 and a. Due to this fact that for an arbitrary vector space we can find several basis, what are other bases of GF(4) as a vector space over GF(2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write

$$\Bbb F_4=GF(4)=\{0,1,a,a+1\}\;,\;\;\text{with the condition}\;\;a^2=a+1$$

From the above representation it follows that $\;\{a\,,\,a+1\}\;$ is linearly independent over $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ and thus we have basis

$$\{1,a\}\;,\;\;\{1,a+1\}\;,\;\;\{a,a+1\}$$

and, of course, the same sets but in reverse order (as a basis is an **ordered** set of linearly independent vectors that generate the linear space)

Comment: Now, I want to define an invertible linear operator on GF(4). Can we say that  the automorphism group of GF(4) is the same as the general linear group, GL(2,2)?

Comment: @user118746 Not only you can: you must...and upvote answers that help you.

Comment: (+1) @user118746: The answer to that extra question depends: Automorphisms as a field or as a vector space over $GF(2)$?

Comment: as a vector space

Comment: My answer thus remains, @user118746 . Jyrki's question is in place, though your question from the beginning talked about vector space...